# Parsing Chrome Bookmarks Json file : Java

Tags: java, json, google-chrome, parsing, netbeans

Currently I am using netbeans IDE. I tried using other solution, but to no luck so far.

Problem is, i am facing errors when trying to **read the Json file** from google Chrome bookmarks file *(C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks)*

p/s: although there is no file type written in the name of Bookmarks, its content have been known as JSON

This is the what inside the Bookmarks.json:

```
{
   "checksum": "20fdfad51db6d3199f8a09c3220dd93b",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "13124893413824227",
            "id": "6",
            "name": "YouTube",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/"
         }, {
            "date_added": "13124893435163243",
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Welcome to Facebook",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
         } ],
         "date_added": "13124893381424539",
         "date_modified": "13124893435163243",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Bookmarks bar",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13124893381424547",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Other bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13124893381424550",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Mobile bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

And here is my code (JsonParser.java):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonParser{
    private static String jsonFile = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Bookmarks";

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader (jsonFile); //access the file
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(reader);

                      String c =(String) jsonObject.get("checksum"); //place
            //        String r =(String) jsonObject.get("roots"); //place

           //   String r =(String) jsonObject.get("children"); //place


                        System.out.println("check: " + c);
                        //System.out.println("roots: " + r);
                       JSONArray lang = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("roots"); 
            for (int i=0; i<lang.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println ("Url Name : " + lang.get(i)+"\n");
            }       //data in the array
            }  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run the code these are the errors I got:

```
check: 4d55f8a0888f7dd918a702eda2821ccd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
at JsonParser.main(JsonParser.java:28)
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Keep-It\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Keep-It\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

As you can see, only ***checksum*** succeed in being read, but the ***roots*** failed and gave out these errors.

You should also notice that there are some codes I put as ***comments***, those are things i tried but still got the errors.

**I hope anyone can help me to get these things working.
Thank you very much for helping**

Comment: `roots` node in `Bookmarks.json` is actually JSONObject, because it's value  is enclosed in `{}` brackets. You can cast node to JSONArray only if it's value is enclosed in `[]` square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is , you cannot cast object to array like `(JSONArray) jsonObject.get("roots");` you have to follow the structure so parse according to object and array as shown below

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(reader);
 String checksum =jsonObject.optString("checksum");

 //  get root object
 JSONObject root = jsonObject.getJSONObject("roots");

 //  get root bookmarks object from root
 JSONObject bookmarks = root.getJSONObject("bookmark_bar");

 //  get root children array from bookmarks 
 JSONArray  childrens = bookmarks.getJSONArray("children");

 JSONObject temp ;
  for (int i=0; i<childrens.size(); i++) {
      // get object using index from childrens array
      temp = childrens.getJSONObject(i);

      // get url
      String url = temp.optString("url");
  }
```

as your structure follow

```
JObject => root 
               root  JSONObject has : bookmark_bar JSONObject 
               bookmark_bar JSONObject has  : children JSONArray
               children JSONArray has JSONObject which further has String: url
```

Comment: yeah I just resolved this problem just now. By changing the arrays and the objects to the proportionate one, i resolved it. The suggestion from the others also useful and same as yours, but with you detailing it like this, I can understand it more easily.

Comment: @user7288944 What is the specific change you made that resolves the issue.  I'm getting the same error that you specified.  I have tried to make the changes suggested by Pavneet Singh, but can't get it to compile.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
 at javaTools.JsonParser.main(JsonParser.java:27)`

Comment: @L.D.James are you sure you are using this exact line code `JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(reader);`

Comment: I have a similar question on the system.  Give me a second to find it.

Comment: @PavneetSingh I made a mistake and edited the wrong space.  I thought I was editing screen.  I thought I was editing my question but edited your answer by mistake.  You can fix it by rejecting the edit.  But at the same time you can see the code I was using.

Comment: Yes.  Everything is the same except for the changes you suggested.

Comment: I found the question.  I'll give you the link as soon as I edit it to include the information you asked.

Comment: @L.D.James [this is the place](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1204365/l-d-james?tab=topactivity) where you found everything what you did on SO and i [guess this is it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601001/how-to-extract-each-element-bookmark-from-a-json-file-as-an-item-using-java) and again delete all unwnated comments , less job for moderators

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601001/how-to-extract-each-element-bookmark-from-a-json-file-as-an-item-using-java

Answer (score 0):

roots is not a JSONArray but a JSONObject.

So what you have to do is

```
JSONObject lang = jsonObject.get("roots");
```

and then you have too loop through all keys in the object which should be:

- bookmark_bar
- other
- synced

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like "roots" is not an array, but an object when looking at the JSON. "children" under "bookmark_bar" is an array however